# Lightning generated html list horizontal alignment issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I recently took over a small project started by another developer, one of the core pieces of this project involves displaying information on a calendar. This calendar is created using Javascript within a salesforce lightning component, the JS creates a an unordered list, and then fills that list with list items which acts as the days. And here lies the problem, whenever information such as a link is displayed within a day, the list item is moved so that the last line of each day lines up with the previous day like this:

Broken calendar days:

[image]

Each list item contains a paragraph tag which contains the day number and if applicable, a link, each separated by a line break.

Here's the javascript within the lightning component:

```
var number = DayNumber(i + 1);
// Check Date against Event Dates
for (var n = 0; n < calendar.Model.length; n++) {
  var evDate = calendar.Model[n].Date;
  var toDate = new Date(calendar.Selected.Year, calendar.Selected.Month, (i + 1));
  if (evDate.getTime() == toDate.getTime()) {
    number.className += " eventday";
    var title = document.createElement('span');
    title.className += "cld-title";
    if (typeof calendar.Model[n].Link == 'function' || calendar.Options.EventClick) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.setAttribute('href', '#');
      a.innerHTML += calendar.Model[n].Title;
      if (calendar.Options.EventClick) {
        var z = calendar.Model[n].Link;
        if (typeof calendar.Model[n].Link != 'string') {
          a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind.apply(calendar.Options.EventClick, [null].concat(z)));
          if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
            day.className += " clickable";
            day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind.apply(calendar.Options.EventClick, [null].concat(z)));
          }
        } else {
          a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind(null, z));
          if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
            day.className += " clickable";
            day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind(null, z));
          }
        }
      } else {
        a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Model[n].Link);
        if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
          day.className += " clickable";
          day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Model[n].Link);
        }
      }
      title.appendChild(a);
    } else {
      title.innerHTML += '<a href="' + calendar.Model[n].Link + '">' + calendar.Model[n].Title + '</a>';
    }
    number.innerHTML += "</br>" + title.innerHTML;
  }
}
day.appendChild(number);
```

They are displayed inline-block and use a border to create the illusion of a calendar. Is there any way to alter or override the way that this list is aligning it's items?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was caused by how unordered lists handled inline alignment. I modified the css of the day elements to include overflow : auto, this adjusted for the vertical alignment issue caused by the text.